# Cant resolve the ActionSupport class in struts 2.3.4 which package and jar?

Tags: java, struts2

I am trying to run the [example](http://www.vaannila.com/struts-2/struts-2-example/object-backed-java-beans-example-1.html) but eclipse cant seem to resolve the ActionSupport class. Could anyone tell me which package and jar should I import ?

Comment: I had the same error the problem was that I did not added the maven dependency in  my project. @MistyD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The full path is

```
com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport
```

Make sure you have the correct packages installed.

Answer (score 5):

For struts 2.3.1.2 
The jar required is :: xwork-core-2.3.1.2.jar. Add that  to your classpath. Check  which version  of xwork you need with the bundle that comes with struts2

**Edit::**
If you have jar in your classpath . simple Ctrl+O(organize imports). If it gives you option .
 select      *com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;*

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to check if everything else is working fine you can try running the project without `com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport`

This way, the sample code will be like:

```
package org.apache.struts.helloworld.action;

import org.apache.struts.helloworld.model.MessageStore;

//import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

public class HelloWorldAction  {
private MessageStore messageStore;

public String execute() {
    messageStore = new MessageStore() ;
    
    return "Success";
}

public MessageStore getMessageStore() {
    return messageStore;
}
}
```