# Struts 2 Ajax Validation - jsonValidation Interceptor

Tags: jsp, struts2

i am trying to integrate the struts dojo plugin in order to use ajax.
i have an error on my JSP when i try to use `<%@ taglib uri="/struts-dojo-tags" prefix="d"%>`.
The error is that he cannot find the tag library "cannot find the tag library descriptor for `/struts-dojo-tags`..

Comment: Please note that the Dojo tags have been deprecated for years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include the struts2-dojo-plugin-x.x.x.jar to your classpath: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/struts_2/struts_ajax_tags.htm

Comment: Are you still getting the error after adding the jar to your classpath?

Comment: i don't have the error for the struts-dojo anymore, now i have another error for the /struts-tags !!

Comment: If you don't need the /struts-tags then dont include it. If you do, then add the struts core jar.

Comment: okey thank u so much.now i have another problem in my method action i have an error, the ActionSupport cannot be resolved to a type !!

Comment: Please see if it helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10985708/cant-resolve-the-actionsupport-class-in-struts-2-3-4-which-package-and-jar